# Redirect to another page using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check weather or not a user is logged in, and if not redirect the user to the login page.

This is the project structure:

[image]

This is the index.php:

```
<?php
include("controller/loginFuncs.php");
checkLogin();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    [HTML CODE HERE]
</html>
```

Here is loginFuncs.php:

```
<?php    
function checkLogin() {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        echo "Calling logout";
        logout();
    }
}

function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['fname'], $_SESSION['lname'], $_SESSION['role']);
    include("../views/login.php");
}
```

In the function `logout()` I also tried using `header("Location: ../views/login.php");` However, it seems header is used only for full url's, and since the project is under development I don't have that url nor would it be good to hard code a url there since the domain could change and then I would have to change the code. I'm looking for a solution that uses the files relative path in the project structure, like include but include doesn't work for some reason.

If I load index.php I get the "Calling logout" message but the login.php is never actually included. The resulting page url is `http://localhost:63342/stm_asc/index.php?_ijt=st357j0vorq8hq8719sq87qga9`

How can I perform redirect the user to the login page if he is not logged in? Thank you.

Comment: `header('Location: ...` is not only for full URLs and there's no reason it shouldn't work with a relative URL.

Comment: If you're viewing `/stm_asc/index.php` and issue `header('Location: ../views/login.php')`, the resulting URL will be `/views/login.php` - is this where your login is actually located? What is the result when you do the `header` call?

Comment: Why would some one down vote this question? I just don't get it, it is a legit question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should user header Function:

```
header('location: file.php');
```

in your case:

```
header('location: /views/login.php');
```

visit [Header Function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp)

Comment: Woth noticing. You MUST NOT have output any data or you will get `headers already sent` error

Comment: That should have worked, except it doesn't the url generate by that is `http://localhost:63342/views/login.php` for some reason is not picking up the projects name, it should have been `http://localhost:63342/stm_asc/views/login.php`

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe Because it would be run from the root directory. Just remove the `../` and it should work, `header('location: views/login.php');`

Comment: try header('location: /views/login.php');

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using codeigniter. If so then this code might help you.

**Controller :**

```
public function index()
{
  $this->load->view('login');
}

public function call_login()
{
    $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $login_result = $this->your_model_name->login_user($uname,$password);

    if($login_result)
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }

    else
    {
        $this->load->view('login',$a);
    }
}
```

**Model :**

```
public function login_user($uname,$password)
{
    $query = $this->db->where('uname',$uname)
                    ->where('password',$password)
                    ->get('users');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And your **View :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="call_login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter username">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help you.